default application credentials giving error in Google Cloud VM - ODBC Drivers for Bigquery
So I am testing a SSIS package connecting to a Bigquery dataset. I have downled and installed the odbc driver from - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers
Now I am getting the error as "Could not validate the GCE environment" by selecting the authentication as "application default credentials" The driver and the dsn is in a Google cloud VM and it is using a compute service account which i can see using the command gcloud auth list. Then I should not be getting this error?


Hi , I have posted an answer, if you find it helpful, please do consider upvoting and accepting it as per stackoverflow guidelines helping more Stack contributors with their research. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer

You can try to choose Authentication type to -  user authentication  .

Updating Simba Google BigQuery ODBC Connector to the latest version 3.0.7 ,  The connector now supports authentication through Application Default Credentials But For some people the newer version shows an error or some people it's working . To get detailed investigation on the issue you can open bug request with details sharing log file on the public issue tracker  and upvote +1 ,Eng team will look on the issue for future implementation Or you can contact Google support team .

